# Check values from similar sub objects properties

Tags: javascript

I'm in a similar situation:

```
 this.state = {    
            globalState:     {
                aState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                bState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                nazfState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                prdState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                vdState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                tesState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''}
            },
            ....
```

Is there a way to check all errorState property is not null?

Now I'm accessing all object this way:

```
 Object.keys(this.state.globalState).forEach(function(key,index) {
            console.log( key); 

        });
```

That prints keys (astate, bstate...)...but can't access errorState value of all properties\objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing this way:

```
Object.keys(state.globalState).forEach(function(key,index) {
    console.log(state.globalState[key].errorState);
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. need to iterate a state object. I access it by this.state...

Comment: I don't know if I got it, but it seems that you should just add "this." before every "state" in the code:
`Object.keys(this.state.globalState).forEach(function(key,index) {
    console.log(this.state.globalState[key].errorState);
});`
(sorry, having a hard time trying to format the code here) =D

Answer (score 0):

Access the `errorState` by `state.globalState[key].errorState`. For demo I have replace `this`

`state.globalState[key]` will give each of the `aState`,`bState`, etc.`state.globalState[key].errorState` will givee the value of the key.

The square bracket is used a variable is used to get a value from object

```js
var state = {
  globalState: {
    aState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    },
    bState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    },
    nazfState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    },
    prdState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    },
    vdState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    },
    tesState: {
      errorState: null,
      errorReport: ''
    }
  }
}


Object.keys(state.globalState).forEach(function(key, index) {
  console.log(state.globalState[key].errorState);

});
```

Comment: doesn't work. need to iterate a state object. I access it by this.state...

Comment: I mentioned for demoing I replaced `this` with var

Answer (score 0):

Use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all of the error states is null or a specific value. Side note - not sure why you want to use `this` , i may not be getting the entire context, the code below is something close to what you are looking for

```js
   this.state = {    
            globalState:     {
                aState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                bState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                nazfState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                prdState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                vdState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''},
                tesState:  { errorState: null, errorReport: ''}
            }
            }

       let errStates = []          
       Object.keys(this.state.globalState).forEach(k => errStates.push(k => k.errorState));
      
      console.log(errStates.every(e => {return e.errorState == null}));
```